# trying to convert .py into .exe, and when i go to the dist folder to run the .exe generated i get a black/blank cmd screen and nothing happens

Tags: pyinstaller, exe

any thoughts? per the warning log, it looks like i am missing a ton of modules (~200) but i am not sure what is relevant or if these are even causing the issue. below is a list of all the missing modules.

Types if import:

- top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
- conditional: imported within an if-statement
- delayed: imported within a function
- optional: imported within a try-except-statement

```
IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
            tracking down the missing module yourself. Thanks!

missing module named pyimod02_importers - imported by C:\Users\jwebb007\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py (top-level), C:\Users\jwebb007\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py (top-level)
missing module named StringIO - imported by PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph.zipio (conditional), setuptools._vendor.six (conditional), six (conditional), pkg_resources._vendor.six (conditional)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named grp - imported by subprocess (optional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), subprocess (optional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), test.support (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level), PyInstaller.loader.pyimod01_archive (delayed)
missing module named pep517 - imported by importlib.metadata (delayed)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (conditional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (conditional)
missing module named ordereddict - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (optional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional), setuptools.sandbox (conditional)
missing module named _manylinux - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.tags (delayed, optional), setuptools._vendor.packaging.tags (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
missing module named 'win32com.shell' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'com.sun' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed)
missing module named win32api - imported by distutils.msvccompiler (optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named win32com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.appdirs - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves' - imported by pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.six - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named numarray - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named Numeric - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named win32con - imported by distutils.msvccompiler (optional)
missing module named _curses - imported by curses (top-level), curses.has_key (top-level)
missing module named 'nose.plugins' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level), numpy.testing._private.nosetester (delayed)
missing module named 'nose.util' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named psutil - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, optional)
missing module named _dummy_thread - imported by cffi.lock (conditional, optional), numpy.core.arrayprint (optional)
missing module named numpy.core.result_type - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.float_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.object_ - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.all - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.bool_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.inf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.array2string - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isscalar - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named win32pdh - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, conditional)
missing module named numpy.core.isinf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.errstate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isfinite - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isnan - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.array - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isnat - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ndarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.array_repr - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.arange - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.empty - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intp - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named numpy.core.linspace - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.index_tricks (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.iinfo - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.twodim_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.transpose - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.function_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.asarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sqrt - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.swapaxes - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.zeros - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.argsort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sign - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.count_nonzero - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.divide - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.matmul - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.asanyarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_2d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.product - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.amax - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.amin - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.moveaxis - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.geterrobj - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.finfo - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sum - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.fastCopyAndTranspose - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.multiply - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.dot - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.Inf - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.newaxis - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.cdouble - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.csingle - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.double - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.single - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intc - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.empty_like - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ufunc - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ones - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.hstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_1d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_3d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.vstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named pickle5 - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (optional)
missing module named numpy.eye - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.core.numeric (delayed)
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.float64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.float32 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.uint64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.uint32 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.uint16 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.uint8 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.int64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.int32 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.int16 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.int8 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level)
missing module named _ufunc - imported by numpy.typing (conditional)
missing module named numpy.bytes_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.str_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.void - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.object_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.datetime64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.timedelta64 - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.number - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.complexfloating - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.floating - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.integer - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.unsignedinteger - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.generic - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level)
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level), numpy.array_api._typing (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing._array_like (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level), pandas.compat.numpy.function (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ufunc - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.typing (top-level)
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.lib.twodim_base (delayed)
missing module named xlwt - imported by pandas.io.excel._xlwt (delayed, conditional)
missing module named xlsxwriter - imported by pandas.io.excel._xlsxwriter (delayed)
missing module named defusedxml - imported by openpyxl.xml (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'defusedxml.ElementTree' - imported by openpyxl.xml.functions (conditional)
missing module named htmlentitydefs - imported by lxml.html.soupparser (optional)
missing module named BeautifulSoup - imported by lxml.html.soupparser (optional)
missing module named bs4 - imported by pandas.io.html (delayed), lxml.html.soupparser (optional)
missing module named urlparse - imported by lxml.html (optional), lxml.ElementInclude (optional), lxml.html.html5parser (optional)
missing module named urllib2 - imported by lxml.ElementInclude (optional), lxml.html.html5parser (optional)
missing module named 'html5lib.treebuilders' - imported by lxml.html.html5parser (top-level)
missing module named html5lib - imported by lxml.html._html5builder (top-level), lxml.html.html5parser (top-level)
missing module named PIL - imported by PyInstaller.building.icon (delayed, optional), PyInstaller.building.splash (optional), openpyxl.drawing.image (optional)
missing module named tests - imported by openpyxl.reader.excel (optional)
missing module named 'odf.config' - imported by pandas.io.excel._odswriter (delayed)
missing module named 'odf.style' - imported by pandas.io.excel._odswriter (delayed)
missing module named 'odf.text' - imported by pandas.io.excel._odfreader (delayed), pandas.io.excel._odswriter (delayed)
missing module named 'odf.table' - imported by pandas.io.excel._odfreader (delayed), pandas.io.excel._odswriter (delayed)
missing module named 'odf.opendocument' - imported by pandas.io.excel._odfreader (delayed), pandas.io.excel._odswriter (delayed)
missing module named xlrd - imported by pandas.io.excel._xlrd (delayed), pandas.io.excel._base (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'odf.element' - imported by pandas.io.excel._odfreader (delayed)
missing module named 'odf.namespaces' - imported by pandas.io.excel._odfreader (delayed)
missing module named odf - imported by pandas.io.excel._odfreader (delayed)
missing module named botocore - imported by pandas.io.common (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'matplotlib.pyplot' - imported by pandas.io.formats.style (optional), pandas._testing._io (delayed), pandas._testing.asserters (delayed)
missing module named matplotlib - imported by pandas.io.formats.style (optional)
missing module named markupsafe - imported by pandas.io.formats.style_render (top-level)
missing module named 'IPython.core' - imported by pandas.io.formats.printing (delayed, conditional)
missing module named IPython - imported by pandas.io.formats.printing (delayed)
missing module named pyarrow - imported by pandas.core.arrays.masked (delayed), pandas.core.arrays.boolean (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.arrays.numeric (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.arrays._arrow_utils (top-level), pandas.core.arrays.interval (delayed), pandas.core.arrays.period (delayed), pandas.io.feather_format (delayed), pandas.core.arrays.string_ (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.arrays.string_arrow (conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes (delayed, conditional), pandas.compat.pyarrow (optional)
missing module named six.moves.range - imported by six.moves (top-level), dateutil.rrule (top-level)
runtime module named six.moves - imported by dateutil.tz.tz (top-level), dateutil.tz._factories (top-level), dateutil.tz.win (top-level), dateutil.rrule (top-level)
missing module named dateutil.tz.tzfile - imported by dateutil.tz (top-level), dateutil.zoneinfo (top-level)
missing module named numba - imported by pandas.core.util.numba_ (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.window.numba_ (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.window.online (delayed, conditional), pandas.core._numba.executor (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.groupby.numba_ (delayed, conditional), pandas.core._numba.kernels.mean_ (top-level), pandas.core._numba.kernels.shared (top-level), pandas.core._numba.kernels.min_max_ (top-level), pandas.core._numba.kernels.sum_ (top-level), pandas.core._numba.kernels.var_ (top-level)
missing module named numexpr - imported by pandas.core.computation.expressions (conditional), pandas.core.computation.engines (delayed)
missing module named 'pyarrow.parquet' - imported by pandas.io.parquet (delayed)
missing module named Foundation - imported by pandas.io.clipboard (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named AppKit - imported by pandas.io.clipboard (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named PyQt4 - imported by pandas.io.clipboard (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named PyQt5 - imported by pandas.io.clipboard (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named qtpy - imported by pandas.io.clipboard (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'sqlalchemy.engine' - imported by pandas.io.sql (delayed)
missing module named 'sqlalchemy.types' - imported by pandas.io.sql (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'sqlalchemy.schema' - imported by pandas.io.sql (delayed)
missing module named sqlalchemy - imported by pandas.io.sql (delayed, conditional)
missing module named tables - imported by pandas.io.pytables (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'scipy.stats' - imported by pandas.core.nanops (delayed, conditional)
missing module named scipy - imported by pandas.core.missing (delayed)
missing module named 'pyarrow.compute' - imported by pandas.core.arrays.string_arrow (conditional)
missing module named sets - imported by pytz.tzinfo (optional)
missing module named UserDict - imported by pytz.lazy (optional)
missing module named 'scipy.sparse' - imported by pandas.core.arrays.sparse.array (conditional), pandas.core.arrays.sparse.scipy_sparse (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.arrays.sparse.accessor (delayed), pandas.core.dtypes.common (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named hypothesis - imported by pandas.util._tester (delayed, optional)
missing module named pytest - imported by pandas._testing._io (delayed), pandas._testing (delayed), pandas.util._tester (delayed, optional)
missing module named pandas.ExtensionArray - imported by pandas (conditional), pandas.core.construction (conditional)
missing module named pandas.UInt64Index - imported by pandas (conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.generic (conditional)
missing module named pandas.Int64Index - imported by pandas (conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.generic (conditional)
missing module named pandas.Float64Index - imported by pandas (conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.generic (conditional), pandas.core.internals.blocks (conditional), pandas.core.indexes.datetimes (conditional), pandas.core.internals.array_manager (conditional)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are using pyinstaller to convert it. Instead of double clicking the exe that you have made from the Python file, I would run it via the terminal or command prompt. Maybe it will show you what error you have. And try using https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/